# Convert hex code in string to hex code in byte (java)

Tags: java

I have a hex code in string
example

```
String a="0x52";
```

I want to store this hex value in a byte
example

```
byte b=(do something with a so i can store it in b);
```

so byte b is going to store 0x52

How to achieve this ?

Just for reference my teacher gave this sample code

```
public  byte[] CONSIGNMENT_0 = { 0x52, 0x44, 0x54, 0x30, 0x31, 0x9, 0x6f, 0x6e,  
                                           0x65, 0xa, 0x32, 0x9, 0x74, 0x77, 0xa, 0xd };
```

And its working perfectly so we can store 0x52 in a byte variable.

Comment: I tried that its not working its giving a run time error NumberFormatException: for input string "0x52"  even Byte.parseByte is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a hex constant, so you can parse it with `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` (the second argument is a base) and then cast it to a `byte`. Like,

```
String a = "0x52";
byte b1 = 0x52;
byte b2 = (byte) Integer.parseInt(a.substring(2), 16);
System.out.println(b1 == b2);
```

Outputs

```
true
```